# Reflection in C++. How to pass a func as a parameter in c++

Tags: c++, function, reflection, methods

I am new to c++. So I'm trying to do something that is trivial but cannot figure out how.

I have a Class called Method:

```
class Method{

private:
    std::string nameMethod;
    Func f;

public:
    Method(std::string name,Func fun){
        nameMethod=name;
        f=fun;
    };
```

I want to create an Object of type Method called methDaniel which has

1. string nameMethod = addDaniel.
2. f = to a function that prints "Daniel".

How do I do this in the main.cpp file?

```
#include "Method.h"

using namespace std;

typedef void (*t_somefunc)();

void addDaniel(){
    cout<<"Daniel";
}


int main(){
    addDaniel();

    t_somefunc afunc = &addDaniel;
    Method* methDaniel = new Method("addDaniel",afunc);

}
```

Comment: Why not simply use a `std::map<std::string,t_somefunc>`? And what's `Func` actually?

Comment: "depends" but I'd probably use a `std::unordered_map<std::string,std::function<FUNC>>` (syntax is a little wrong, but you get the idea)

Comment: You don't need `new` to create an object in C++.

Comment: Just as a complete aside to the problem, a `function` in C++ is known as a `method` in many other OO languages, and the term is commonly used interchangeably. This may be a failing on my part, and it's certainly not an outright error, but a class called method looks potentially confusing and just generally reads incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `typedef` for defining `t_somefunc` to "Method.h".

Change the type of `f` from `Fun` to `t_somefunc`.

Method.h:

```
typedef void (*t_somefunc)();

class Method{

private:
    std::string nameMethod;
    t_somefunc f;

public:
    Method(std::string const& name, t_somefunc fun) : nameMethod(name), f(fun){}
```

Then, in `main`:

```
Method* methDaniel = new Method("addDaniel", addDaniel);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. 

Let's say that

 typedef void (*t_somefunc)(Object*);

How would I pass the object into the function in the main method?